# Automatic bulk snapping with FOSS

Tags: qgis, postgis, open-source-gis, free-software

I'm looking for a tool that would be able to automatically snap features closer than a given distance. Is there such a tool/plugin for QGIS/GRASS/OpenJump? Would it be possible to achieve that with PostGIS?

I have a river network where some of tributaries don't touch the river they flow in and I need to get them snapped.

Comment: Try v.clean.snap from GRASS QGIS. In PostGIS avaiable ST_SnapToGrid () function

Comment: v.clean.snap seems to be doing a great job! Thank you.

Comment: If two rivers touch, how do I tell which one is a tributary? I tried with ST_EndPoint(), but obviously some of the tributaries touch the river at the StartPoint as there is no way to tell which point it actually starts at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GRASS GIS, you can use [v.edit](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.edit.html) for this. There is "    snap: Snap vector features in given threshold" along with the possibility to define a box or polygon to spatially constrain the snapping to a certain area in the map as well as "where" to constrain with attribute selection.