# Real time map matching using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, snapping, real-time

I am working on a project which requires real time map matching. I am currently using ArcGIS but not sure whether it will work.

Here is what happens with my system:

the cell phones sent GPS fixes every five seconds to my server and I need to do real time map matching to snap the point on to one of the links of the map and store the matched points.

ArcGIS has a 'near' tool for snapping the point to nearest link. However, the input to the tool has to be a shapefile for the points.

I am wondering how I can deal with the real time data I get in ArcGIS. Creating a shape file for each point?

Any other suggestion for accomplish this work?

Answer (score 3):

Create a point feature from your GPS location (presumably stored as a table format file) using [Make XY Event](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Make_XY_Event_Layer/00170000006z000000/) and [Copy Features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Copy_Features/001700000035000000/) and then use this with the [Near](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Near/00080000001q000000/) tool - or try the [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) tool with the 'closest' option. You will likely want to store these intermediate features in a temporary/scratch workspace that can be deleted after obtaining the final output (which you could [Append](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Append/001700000050000000/) to your database).

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your help. I did exactly the way you said and it is solved now. However, there is a new problem. The computation takes seven to ten seconds to print the final results for a point. But what I can developing is a real time application which is better to be controlled within at most 2 to 3 seconds. Is the import of Arcpy the problem since this is a large module? Could you please tell me where the problem is and any way to improve the system? (The whole system is in Java, The python  module I developed will be called from the main codes)

Comment: So It seems that the arcpy is imported every time. Is this where the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome to the first comment. As for your second comment, I recommend that you post a new question (perhaps with reference to this original one) about how to improve your code, along with the example code so we can all assess it better.

Answer (score 1):

If a point is 'near' really depends on many things not just on the closest road but also on previous points. You can have a look into the [algorithm and tools](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/digitalizing-gpx-points-or-how-to-track-vehicles-with-graphhopper/) that I would use.

Answer (score 1):

There's a real-time map matching solution (however it's in Java not ArcGIS) that implements Hidden Markov Model map matching, see here: https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot

It's quite robust and map matches GPS tracks to OpenStreetMap data, also in real-time (referred to as online map matching). (UPDATE:) What you may be looking for is implemented as a "tracker stand-alone server" (with a REST-like API).

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Would you know if this functionality is present now?

Comment: Well, yes this functionality is available now but it's not part of ArcGIS (if this is the question). The result looks like this: https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot#tracker-server-quick-start

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to run into computational bottlenecks and consistency problems with any package that doesn't have a proper routing or at the minimum a road network abstraction. 
If you are using OSM data for the road network, check TrackMatching from my profile. Check [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas/62746#62746) map-matching algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at new service API of microsoft 'Snap to road'. For details you can see this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/snap-to-road)