# How to match GPS collected data to routes on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, gps, routing, map-drawing, map-matching

I am using Google Maps to implement a GPS Monitoring system of data collected from vehicles. My problem occurs when the points and lines do not match with the route and cut through other streets and structures such as shown in the example below.

**How can I solve this problem?**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You need to do some map-matching. For that to work out, you need access to the underlying data. This might not be possible with google maps. See this for more details: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas

Comment: While you may be able to find a solution for _some_ cases, it won't work every time.  Think about what's going to happen when you end up in a high rise area - or any area - with little to no GPS signal.  The app can't intelligently guess where you're going, so why do you expect it to?  You obviously need more training in how this 'stuff' works.

Comment: @Geoist and how do gps tracking applications draw the route ?

Comment: @opc0de Firstly, you have 2 waypoints over the span of what looks like 500m.  Trying to interpolate and superimpose your position between those 2 points is impossible.  Google maps can guess where you drove, but with absolutely no certainty unless you have additional accelerometer, wheel tracking data as well.  Consumer based products use a combination of high sample rate (1/sec), possible accelerometer data, and complex algorithms that take into account street length, turning time, street direction data etc.  Source: I've designed such algorithms that are used in production globally.

Comment: @Geoist thanks a lot, the devices I use have a bad habbit of sending data slowly and sometimes not accurate at all. Chinese...products. So do you think I need to change them in order to acheive a decent result?

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [trackMatching](https://mapmatching.3scale.net/). Its free, efficient and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to Google maps, they have also released an experimental "Tracks API" which does that. See
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tracks/

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few GPS points, you may be able to use the [waypoint functionality](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints) of the directions API and have Google calculate the routing. This may not reflect the actual route taken, of course, but I doubt thats possible anyway, unless you have other data.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to get more coordinate readings from your GPS device. When you have more GPS coordinates taken is shorted time interval, then you have more points on the map and when you join the lines through the points you will get more precise track.

The current results, shows that your GPS device collected GPS coordinate less frequently or the car was traveling too fast or both case.

Answer (score -1):

The snap to roads feature might help here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap