# Adjusting GPS collected data to a polyline shapefile

Tags: python, gps, routing, spatial-adjustment

I am collecting data from a GPS that is attached to a car. When I display this data in a map, the set of collected points are supposed to match with the street shapefile. However what I see in my map is points overlying places where the car can't go, Ex. Buildings, Parcels etc.

I understand this is a GPS accuracy issue. My question is: Is there any script or any way to spatially adjust this points to place them on top of the line so the collected data display on its right position in the map.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas?

Comment: I have used this in the past: https://mapmatching.3scale.net/