# Making Map Matching Points to Roads

Tags: qgis, cartography, map-matching

I'm having some trouble while map matching these points for some streets. Could you lend me a hand?

[image]

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: I don't see how to map matching the points with lines

Comment: Could you expand on your question?  What do the points represent?  What do the lines represent?  Please provide explicit details on what goal you are trying to accomplish, steps you have already attempted, or ideas that you have but do not know how to implement.

Comment: Points represent Trucks dataset consists of 276 trajectories of 50 trucks delivering concrete to several construction places around Athens metropolitan area in Greece for 33 distinct days.

Lines represent the streets of Athens. I still can't do anything, I had all day to search and nothing

Comment: Some other keywords to search: snapping GPS points to streets.

Answer (score 2):

The solution will largely depends on the frequency of your data (e.g. every 100m or every minute, etc.). If your data is dense enough, the problem is called "map-matching". If the data is very sparse it's called "Path inference". Some GIS such as ArcGIS network analyst can help you with problem #1. I'd suggest you take a look at [this discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas?rq=1) . If you're after a web-service for map-matching, check TraxMatching from my profile.