# How to find similar GPS tracks considering timestamps?

Tags: gps, algorithm, similarity

There are around 300 users tracks per day with about 4k points in each with 10s time interval. I'd like to find similar tracks considering location and time.
The tracks are similar if it can be assumed that two users where moving together (close locations during 30s timeframe) for the most of the track.

I have already seen similar rather old questions:
[How to find if two gps tracks were from the same trip?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127925/how-to-find-if-two-gps-tracks-were-from-the-same-trip) and
[Matching GPS tracks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81551/matching-gps-tracks)
but none of them answers what algorithm can be used find a time-based solution.

Maybe there are some new ideas after 5 years?