# How to count near intersecting polylines and merge them?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, gps, line

I have a dataset with several polylines created by GPS points of car trips. I am trying to create a simple heatmap where roads with more traffic (where polylines intersect) get darker.

I already tried overlapping each polyline and then applying a sligh opacity to each one and that works. The problem is that with huge amounts of data, the request to the server for the data is too big.

My idea is, in the server, process each trip and merge each overlapping polyline into a single one with and associated weight. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Although not PostGIS, here is a Python solution to a similar problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/81736/40793   (And I bet you could leverage PostGIS's spatial index to do it in-database, if that is a requirement.)