# Auto Generate kml files along the roads for more than 8 points

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

**What I am trying to do:** Auto Generate kml files for bus routes.

**Input:** Bus stop list for each route with name and lat/long (every list has more than >30 bus stops.)

**Output:** kml file of the route passing through the bus stops and along the roads.

**Research so far:**

1. Found [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_multipleWayPts_CustomMrkrsB.html) tool from geocodezip.com to plot routes with more than 8 points.
2. Found [this](http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html) excellent tool to write kml files from manually clicked points. It works beautifully for less than 8 way-points.

**Possible direction:** Ideally I want to combine the functionality of both the the above tools and have a tool that writes kml code for routes without restriction on no. of waypoints.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do comes under the field of Map Matching or conflation. Early last year, as a personal project, I tried something similar.

I used the answers on this question: [Different approaches for map matching : links / ideas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas)

I ended up using the the Service available at: https://mapmatching.3scale.net/

I already had data for the bus stops in GPX Format. I just used that on the Deom page, and then using the REST API.

If your data is not in GPX format, you can easily convert it in a software like Qgis.

Comment: As far as I understand, map matching is when the points are away from the roads, and they have to be projected to their closest point on the road. The points that I have are already on the road (even the correct lane). I just have to use these points to plot a route and export it to kml/shp etc.

Comment: Think of this way: You might have bus stops every 500 m along the road. If you just join these points, you will have a jagged path. What you need is a path which will follow the curves of the road. This can be done in an automated way, only with Map matching.