# Finding routes in which more than one car passed (gps data)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, gps, point, spatial-statistics

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1. I have point GPS data of routes of several cars over a few days,  and I want to find only the routes where more than one or two different cars passed through (Each GPS points has the car id in it). How can I find a thing like that without going through the data manually ?

EDIT: The time interval (and the distance) between points differs - it moves from minutes to hours and from a few meters to tens of kilometers apart. I'm comparing routes right now by viewing the points by the eye (which isn't accurate or useful in any way). I thought about creating routes using network analyst, but as I have a lot of points I kind of hoped to fan out the less popular ways first, and calculating routes for only the popular ones...

Comment: What is the time interval of your GPS returns? This makes a big difference on how you create routes. From my experience, anything more than 10 seconds and you are probably going to need to network dataset.

Comment: What is the distance between points along the route, or the time interval as asked by @blord? There are a few solutions but this is an important part of the question!

Comment: Are you defining the 'routes where ... cars passed' as a whole segment travelled OR that the cars passed a certain _point_ along that route?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the **[Points To Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003s000000)** tool first to create lines for each route from your GPS points.

I would then **[Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000)** these lines by a distance that you experiment with - it will be related to how much variation there is in your GPS accuracy.

The last step will be to **[Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000)** your buffers to see where they (i.e. your car routes) overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I would do "[map-matching](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas/62746#62746)" of all your high sample GPS data or shortest paths for the low sample data. Then keep only the road segments for which there is a substantial amount of traffic (arbitrarily defined by your needs). Then keep the routes which used at least one of these segments. ( Disclaimer: check my profile for the map-matching API).