# Is there Open Source equivalent to ArcGIS Integrate (for topology correction)?

Tags: open-source-gis, topology, tesselation

I need to transform a set of polygons so that it forms an exact spatial partition/tesselation (no gap - no overlap). What are the existing open-source solutions (software or library) to perform this correction? Ideally, I am looking for open-source versions of the ArcGIS [integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000).

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

Comment: What is the format of the data?

Comment: whatever format...

Comment: What kind of 'surfaces' are they? Draped 3D polygons of some kind? Or do you mean 'areas', i.e. 2D polygons?

Comment: Is it like "vector conflation"? Then see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58536/687

Comment: @Simbamangu: by 'surface', I mean polygon (correction done).

Comment: @markusN: Thanks, but it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Update 2018-05-11: in QGIS 2.18 and 3.0, this is done much more easily (no need to set up a mapset).

1. Open the v.clean tool in the Processing toolbox.
2. Select 'snap' as the cleaning tool.
3. Set the `v.in.ogr` tolerance as per the instructions below (250 in the example).
4. Run the tool, and you'll get two new layers - one 'errors' and one 'cleaned'.

Experiment for the right amount of snapping to use - see notes at the end.

---

You can use a number of GRASS tools to do the job. Just adding the data to a mapset in GRASS using `v.in.ogr.qgis` may be all you need to do. Using QGIS and GRASS:

#### Overview:

1. Open QGIS and make sure the GRASS plugin is turned on (`Plugins|Manage...`) and visible (`View|Toolbars|GRASS`).
2. Add the layer to QGIS.
3. Create a mapset in GRASS.
4. Import the layer into GRASS **using an appropriate snapping threshold**.
5. Export your data (right-click and save-as from QGIS) back to a format you need.

#### In detail:

Add your layer that needs gaps / overlaps cleaned up (this is a UTM layer in metres):

[image: Overview of unclean geometry]

There are some 'bad' areas that fit your description here (overlaps / gaps):

[image]

Select the button on the GRASS toolbar to create a new GRASS mapset:

[image: Toolbar selecting GRASS mapset]

You can just use a temporary folder and temporary location name ...

[image: GRASS setup dialogs]

...and finally a mapset:

[image]

Import your layer from QGIS with the "Open GRASS tools" button then browsing to the tool:

[image: selecting v.in.ogr.qgis]

Select your layer, then click 'advanced' and select an appropriate snapping threshold (in this case, 250m - depends on what your data look like!):

[image]

Results - original in gray, newly snapped layer in maroon:

[image]

NOTE:

- Small gaps and overlaps get fixed without modifying shapes too much, but the larger the 'snap' the more distortion you may see.
- The result is a topologically 'clean' geometry, following all of GRASS's rules (read up on that!).
- There are a LOT of tools (v.clean for one) that can do all kinds of cleaning and fixing.

Comment: Has this been removed from QGIS 3?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: It's been made simpler - see my edit.