# Simplify/generalize Polygons and keep topology of different layers PostGIS/QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, topology, simplify, generalization

I have some polygons of a country, states, districts, communities and I want to simplify the geometry.

I already simplified the geometry of each layer  but afterwards of course it doesnt **fit with the geometry of the higher or lower administrative level**.

I tried https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiSimplifyPreserveTopology
and mapshaper.org.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to show how your simplified layers do not fit the other administrative levels? The GRASS tool **v.generalize** is quite a powerful tool in simplifying whilst maintaining topology as asked in [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/how-to-generalize-a-polygon-file-and-maintain-topology-in-qgis) which _might_ help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach I guess is using real topology data.

Then you can share the edges between data sets and simplify as much as you want.

Here is an example from the man behind the topology implimentation in PostGIS.

http://strk.keybit.net/blog/2013/03/08/on-the-fly-simplification-of-topologically-defined-geometries/

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the [integrate tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000) in ArcGIS. Unfortunately, it is not available as-is in qgis/postgis (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92131/is-there-open-source-equivalent-to-arcgis-integrate-for-topology-correction)) but a workaround exists with GRASS: See [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/92154/162) !

Answer (score 1):

Martin Davis has done the foundation work and the PostGIS team have now implemented this capability.

https://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2023/03/simplifying-polygonal-coverages-with-jts.html
and
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_CoverageSimplify.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting from QGIS 3.36 there are some algorithms on vector coverages

https://www.qgis.org/it/site/forusers/visualchangelog336/index.html#feature-vector-coverage-algorithms