# Map Matching GPS to Road Network

Tags: gps, road, map-matching

I'm working on a project for which I have GPS points and I would like to extract the sequence of roads related to those points. I know that this is called "map-matching" and that there is a load of literature about it.

Here is my question: is there a software / library that allows to easily convert a sequence of GPS points into a road sequence, given that I have the road network, so that I don't have to (re)implement the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively detailed discussion on this topic [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas/62746#62746) which is still largely valid.

Afaik there are few if any library to perform map-matching out of the box. It depends also on which data you're using for the road network. In the case of OpenStreetMap (OSM), take a look at my profile for ref to an available API.