# Mapping Points to streets

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, streets

I am new to the GIS-World and just learned a couple of tools. Now I want to start with my actual project, but since i don't have a overall understanding I would have to hear your opinions about the feasability of my ideas.

I have a lot of data points which refer to car drives getting tracked by GPS. I want to group points which are really close to each other to be able to compare their sensor values.

First I thought of rounding their values to something around 5 decimal places to group them, but then the points would not lie on the street anymore.

My actual plan is to load german street data from OpenStreetMap-Data using osm2pgsql into PostGIS. Then I want to calculate the distance of my data points to the closest street using somehow (maybe ST_Distance). Then I would like to find some algorithm to group points on the street by some flexibel interval (e.g. 5 meters).

Do you think this might work? Any other tools or data I should have a look for? Just trying to minimize programming time invest into some system which might not be able to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't really like to answer own posts, but I just found another [gis stackexchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas) which lists ideas and tools for "map-matching" which seems to be the agreed term for this kind of tasks. Propably there you will find answers if this question is meaningfull to you.

Comment: Always great if people can answer their own questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a [topology](http://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html) and setting a snap tolerance for your streets and points.