# Joining multiple GPS traces to a road

Tags: postgis, line, gps, road

I have multiple GPS traces (polylines) from cars. I would like merge them somehow to create roads. I don't have access to maps in this solution so basically I'm trying to create a poor man's map, with roads by looking where cars go.

So I have multiple polylines created from pretty inaccurate GPS receivers and I need somehow determine that which ones are from cars traveling on the same road.

Then I would like to merge them into a road using some kind of average.

Surely this must be a common problem, but I don't even know what to google... There must be some GIS term for this that I'm not aware of...

I have the data in Postgis but could do this in memory if it is easier...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/different-approaches-for-map-matching-links-ideas

Comment: Well, I *think* I'm asking for something else. My gis skills can't match that question to my problem anyway...