# How to combine lines from different sources reperesenting the same road network but with slightly different geometry?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form, merge, conflation

I have got two layers of polylines which represent the same road network but they are from different sources and have different geometry.
The two layers are mostly the same tracks with larger or smaller offsets and a segmentation that is very different. But each layer contains objects that do not appear in the other. Concerning the attributes, they are different and both contain interesting information that would be desirable to retain the maximum.

I'd like to combine these two layers to have a complete network, which includes the maximum of information contained in the source layers attributes.

I have not been able to get satisfactory results in ArcGIS10 nor in Safe's FME.

Comment: We may be more helpful if you give some more details regarding your desired result/output.  For example, do you want the two polyline datasets to connect to each other, or just copy/paste features from one dataset to the other? Or are you expecting the attributes from one dataset to transfer over to the features in the other?  Do you want the lines from one dataset to change their coordinates to match the other dataset?

Comment: For possible programmatic approaches, see this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/algorithms-for-matching-segments

Answer (score 3):

The process you should check into is often referred to as 'conflation' and the [Java Conflation Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/JCS/) is the first place to look. Not Arc-based, but if you haven't had luck, this is worth a try.